# Product of generated $\sigma$-algebras

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(E_1, \mathcal{F}_1)$ and $(E_2,\mathcal{F}_2)$ be two measurable spaces where $\mathcal{F}_1 = \sigma(\mathcal{E}_1)$ and $\mathcal{F}_2 = \sigma(\mathcal{E}_2)$ with $\mathcal{E}_1 \subset \mathcal{P}(E_1)$ and
$\mathcal{E}_2 \subset \mathcal{P}(E_2)$.

The product $\sigma$-algebra on $E_1 \times E_2$ is
$$
\mathcal{F}_1 \otimes \mathcal{F}_2 = \sigma \big( A_1 \times A_2, A_1 \in \mathcal{F}_1, A_2 \in \mathcal{F}_2 \big )
$$

My question is, do we have the equality:
$$
\mathcal{F}_1 \otimes \mathcal{F}_2 = \sigma \big( A_1 \times A_2, A_1 \in \mathcal{E}_1, A_2 \in \mathcal{E}_2 \big )
$$
?

The inclusion $\sigma \big( A_1 \times A_2, A_1 \in \mathcal{E}_1, A_2 \in \mathcal{E}_2 \big ) \subset \mathcal{F}_1 \otimes \mathcal{F}_2$ seems true to me since $\mathcal{E}_1 \times \mathcal{E}_2 \subset \sigma(\mathcal{E}_1) \times \sigma(\mathcal{E}_2)$ but I don't know what to do for the other inclusion (if it's true of course).

Comment: it holds whenever $E_j\in \mathcal{E}_j$ for $j=1,2$. The proof can be seen in the textbook *Analysis III* of Amann and Escher, page 12. Im too lazy to reproduce it here, sorry.